# How to create an object with relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have two models, i want to create an object Theme, so far i can create Product but i can not create Theme, i dont know why

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord 
  has_many :themes 
end
```

and

```
class Theme < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :products
  
end
```

with this function i am trying to create

```
  def create
    @product = Product.find(3)
    @theme = Theme.create(title:'theme' ,description:'description',  products_id: @product)
  end
```

my migrations are:

```
class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    create_table :products do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :description
      t.integer :price

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

and

```
class CreateThemes < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    create_table :themes do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.string :description
      t.belongs_to :products, null: false, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

i am getting this warning error with this sentence

```
@theme = Theme.create(title:'theme' ,description:'description',  products_id: @product.id)
```

this error:

"#<NameError: Rails couldn't find a valid model for Products association. Please provide the :class_name option on the association declaration. If :class_name is already provided, make sure it's an ActiveRecord::Base subclass.\n\n          raise NameError, msg\n          ^^^^^>",

Comment: Try with `product_id` instead of `products_id`.

Comment: Whenever you cannot create a record with `create` try using instead `new` and checking if your object is valid, then you can check the errors in case it's not valid for insertion/update

Comment: @AmoskalescapingfromRussia i am getting this error ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'product_id' for Theme.

Comment: @AmoskalescapingfromRussia if i use products_id i am not getting any error

Comment: Yeah, you're right, so forget my first comment. You should use `products_id`. Try with `new` and checking if your object is `valid`, and see the errors afterwards (`obj = Theme.new(...); obj.valid?; obj.errors`)

Comment: Or try instead `products_id: @product.id`, as `products_id` is expecting an integer value, not a whole object.

Comment: @AmoskalescapingfromRussia i am getting in console this 07/Oct/2022:20:20:08 +0000] "POST /themes HTTP/1.1" 204 - 1.6858

Comment: Is that the rails console? Try there if you haven't

Comment: but i am still getting empthy array  Theme.all

Comment: @AmoskalescapingfromRussia from console i did this: Theme.create(title:'theme' ,description:'description',  products_id: 5) now i am getting this error  Rails couldn't find a valid model for Products association. Please provide the :class_name option on the association declaration. If :class_name is already provided, make sure it's an ActiveRecord::Base subclass. (NameError)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly your association and migration are wrong. By convention when you use `belongs_to`, you need to use singular, not plural

To fix schema, you need to create new migration (usually changing old migrations is bad idea)

```
change_table :themes do |t|
  t.remove_belongs_to :products, null: false, foreign_key: true
  t.belongs_to :product, null: false, foreign_key: true
end
```

This will create `product_id` and delete `products_id` column in `themes` table

Than change association to

```
class Theme < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product
end
```

And finally to create theme of specific product:

```
product.themes.create(title: 'theme', description: 'description')
```

`product_id` will assign automatically, you don't need specify it